# Binding linux commands

Tags: command-line, bash

Friends,

Is it possible within Linux CLI on Ubuntu to create a script that executes a specific command?

I'm not sure how to call this, but I think it's best explained by an example:

Let's say when I write `"checkMyCurl"` in the command line, it would exec a `"curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://www.something.com/"` command and output the result. Basically I'm just trying to bind a simple command to execute a larger command so that I wouldn't have to write the complicated command all the time.

Thank you! :)

Comment: For this case, you could use a simple *shell alias* - see [Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) in the GNU Bash documentation

Comment: @steeldriver this worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for! Awesome!

Comment: @masch1na you're welcome - see also [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)